# How can I prevent an IntegrityError when adding the same entity to a session twice?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The (executable) code below causes an `IntegrityError` because an entity with the same PK is added twice (implicitly) to the session. The session does not know that the entity represents the same object (same PK) and triggers two `INSERT` statements. I was under the impression that the session was supposed to detect that automatically. I realise that both entities are transient/detached and I would need to perform a `merge` to get a managed instance. But is this not avoidable?

A few notes concerning the example code:

- It's immensely simplified to demonstrate the issue at hand. The real code I have is quite a bit more complex.
- An important thing to note is that the main entity is "built" using a function "build_data" which does not have any reference to the session. The session is created on a higher level of the application.
- The concept of `User` and `Article` are just for illustration. In reality it's different business entities. I replaced them here with "article" and "user" as it's a well-known concept.
- Between the creation of `article` and `article2` a lot of other stuff is happening, creating a fairly complex data-structure. I also don't know which line is happening first as a non-deterministic loop is involved (over dictionary keys).

I could likely solve this by either:

- Passing the session to the `build_data` function and `merging` as required, or
- Keep a manual reference to the instances and only create them once

What I would like to know: **Can I avoid both approaches above to keep the code simple?**

Here's the code in question:

```
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Column,
    ForeignKeyConstraint,
    Unicode,
)
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    relationship,
    sessionmaker)

Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    name = Column(Unicode, nullable=False, primary_key=True)


class Article(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'article'
    __table_args__ = (
        ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ['user_'],
            ['user.name'],
            ondelete='CASCADE',
            onupdate='CASCADE'),
    )
    user_ = Column(Unicode, nullable=False, primary_key=True,
                   )
    title = Column(Unicode, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    content = Column(Unicode)

    user = relationship(User, backref='articles')


# Prepare the session
Session = sessionmaker()
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
Session.configure(bind=engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


# --- The main code -----------------------------------------------------------
def build_data():
    user = User(name='JDoe')
    article = Article(user=user, title='Hello World', content='Foobar')
    print(article)

    # More stuff is happening here.

    article2 = Article(user=user, title='Hello World', content='Foobar')
    print(article2)
    return user

session = Session()
entity = build_data()
session.add(entity)
session.flush()
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```